# Quickest way to randomly re-order a LINQ collection?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have a List

I would like to re-order it so so they are in random order.

What's the quickest way to do this (by quickest, I mean least amount of code)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Randomize a List<T> in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to randomly re-order *in place* you should shuffle the list, usage with an extension method is then a simple one-liner. This assumes you already have an `IList` based collection.

**Usage:** `myList.Shuffle();`

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    Random rng = new Random();  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) 
    {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
```

Credit goes to this answer: [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c/1262619#1262619)

Answer (score 12):

> **Note:** as per mquander's comment, the following answer is not the recommended way to perform "random ordering" since it's semantically incorrect, is not efficient compared to the accepted shuffle algorithm, it's based on the private implementation details of `Guid`s, 
>   and even abuses LINQ query syntax. However, it is the "least amount of code" (in terms of written by oneself as opposed to handled by the framework) as
>   requested by the OP.

```
var randomOrdering = yourList.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid());
```

Comment: Neither nice nor elegant.  If you want to "order by a random number," then generate random numbers, don't generate GUIDs.  And if you want to shuffle a list, use a shuffling algorithm, don't "order by a random number."

Comment: mquander : I used the other solution which worked well but out of curiousity, why isn't this answer good? Does it take much more time to generate a GUID than it is to generate a random number?

Comment: @mquander - updated answer to reflect why it's not the best solution, thanks.

Comment: out of curiosity - why not simply use data.OrderBy(o => rnd.Next());?